# Can I "convert" Console.Writeline console commands into Web Service Web instruction to get a XML-read into webpage scripting?

Tags: c#, api, visual-studio-2012, xml-parsing, push-notification

this is my problem:
I need to write a web service that, installed on a Server (server-1), can comunicate to a mail-Server (server-2).
The trick is: when I send a mail to the mail-server, since I have a PushNotificationSubscriber opened with it, the mailserver will send me the content of the First Mail it founds in the inbox.
But, the content will be written by the server in XML, and then comunicated to the Server-1.
The server-1 will also parse this XML to get Object type data to comunicate with a DB.

Is there a way to do this? Now I can Writedown my codes used:

SERVER-1 CODE:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;

namespace HelloWorld
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);

        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("mail_server_user", "mail_server_pass", "mail_server_domain");

        service.TraceEnabled = true;
        service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
        service.Url = new Uri("https://__Mail_Server's_URI__);


        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(
            WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
            new ItemView(1));
        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter("C:/Results.txt", false))
        {
            foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
            {
                EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id);
                email.Load();

                w.WriteLine(item.Subject);
                w.WriteLine(email.From.Address);
                w.WriteLine(email.Body);

                Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
                Console.WriteLine(email.From.Address);
                Console.WriteLine(email.Body);
            }
        }

        PushSubscription s = service.SubscribeToPushNotifications(
             new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Inbox },
             new Uri("http://Server1_servicepage:XXXX_Port/api/SendNotification"),
             1,
             String.Empty,
             new EventType[] { EventType.NewMail }
             );
    }

    private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
    {
        // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
        bool result = false;

        Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);
        // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
        // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
        // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
        if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
        {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
  }
}
```

SERVER-2 CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;

namespace NotificationAPI.Controllers
{
public class SendNotificationController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Index()
    {
        HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
        String stringContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter("C:/received.txt", true))
        {
            w.WriteLine(stringContent);
        }

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        }

        }
        }
```

As I said, I've tried many times, but I don't get where I am getting losing with it.
and since I'm new in C#, maybe, copy and pasting some code, I haven't done a good job :)
Also, If I have get it wrong, can someone explains me why is wrong? thanks in advice,

Daniel.